# How to stop a window from disposing when someone tries to close it

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I'm pretty new to rcp applications in eclipse and am stuck on a problem. 
I have a window that I don't want to dispose when someone tries to close it. Instead I want to   make it invisible. For that I found the following code

```
parent.getShell().addShellListener(new ShellAdapter(){
   public void shellClosed(ShellEvent e) {
   e.doit = false;
}
```

This should prevent the window from closing, but instead does nothing. I checked whether the method shellClosed is called, and it indeed is, but e.doit = false doesn't seem to have any effect.
Anyone got an idea what I'm doing wrong or how to do it properly?

Answer (score 1):

`shellClosed` is the wrong method. As the name suggests it gets called **after** the shell is closed.

Copied from http://www.java2s.com :

```
shell.addListener(SWT.Close, new Listener() {
  public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    int style = SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.YES | SWT.NO;
    MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox(shell, style);
    messageBox.setText("Information");
    messageBox.setMessage("Close the shell?");
    event.doit = messageBox.open() == SWT.YES;
  }
});
```

EDIT: of course you can leave out the Message box entirely.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunatly that doesn't work. I tried that before. It tells me that my widget is already disposed.
It seems to be called after the window closed as well :\

Comment: This then brings you closer to the solution: My guess is, that there is a listener attached (maybe to the close button as well, I cannot say for sure) that closes the shell **programmatically** before your listener get's called. Such a problem is hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

```
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            JFrame myFrame = (JFrame)e.getSource();
            myFrame.setVisible(false);//don't dispose just hide it
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks to you too. I tried to implement a windowClosing method, which a ShellAdapter apparently doesn't have.